# Python regex issue with negative numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am working with Python and RobotFramework.  In my tests, I grab numbers (in string format, like $486,100,  -23,000) and convert them to integers for comparison.

I have no problems with the positive numbers, my regex removes the dollar signs and commas and leaves me with a number.  However, with the negative number, my regex also removes the "-", so the number is no longer negative.  Need a regex that will keep all digits but also keep the sign as well.

In Selenium IDE, this regex works correctly: `replace(/[^\\d-]/g, '')`

However, since I'm using python in robot, this is the code I have:

```
string_str = re.sub(r'\D', "", string_str)
```

I've looked around and tried modifying it thusly:

```
string_str = re.sub(r'-?\D', "", string_str)
```

and:

```
string_str = re.sub(r'[-]?\D', "", string_str)
```

But so far no success.

Comment: You say you want to "grab" numbers, but you're actually replacing characters in a string. Is your real goal to do string replacement, or to get the number? Do you have to worry about weirdly formatted strings such as -10-20 or 4.5.6?

Comment: I'm storing text from a table on a webpage, the "numbers" are strings that I need to convert to an integer for comparing.  They are all dollar amounts, with no decimal places(cents).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the  same regex.

```
string_str = re.sub(r'[^-\d]', "", string_str)
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I was sure I had tried that, but I tried many combinations....must have missed that one.

Answer (score 11):

I am using this pattern to extract numbers from a string as a list:

```
text = 'fa lkjaf 3 889898 -9.09808 * 2.8999 +809003.22 -19 =2-3  =33-77-9.3'
import re
lt = re.findall('-?\d+\.?\d*',text)
print(lt)
```

['3', '889898', '-9.09808', '2.8999', '809003.22', '-19', '2', '-3', '33', '-77', '-9.3']